# explode a char array

Tags: c++, arduino

I have 2 microcontrollers that do communicate to each other through encrypted radiofrequencies.

The unencrypted data obeys to following pattern : `recipient^send^rollingcode^message^checksum`

example : `BAL^HUB^123^dark=456^2549230589` which means HUB sent a message to BAL, with rolling code 123, saying `dark=456`, where crc32 checksum equals 2549230589

I want BAL to explode that whole data packet.

```
void rxProcess() {
  char tmp[RX_MSG_MAX_LENGTH] = "BAL^HUB^123^dark=456^2549230589";
  char *strTokIndex = strtok(tmp, "^");

  // to
  char to[32] = {0};
  strcpy(to, strTokIndex); // BAL
  serialPrintln(to);

  // from
  strTokIndex = strtok(NULL, "^");
  char from[32] = {0};
  strcpy(from, strTokIndex); // HUB
  serialPrintln(from);

  // rc
  strTokIndex = strtok(NULL, "^");
  uint32_t rc = atol(strTokIndex); // 123
  serialPrintln(rc);

  // msg
  strTokIndex = strtok(NULL, "^");
  char msg[RX_MSG_MAX_LENGTH] = {0};
  strcpy(msg, strTokIndex); // dark=456
  serialPrintln(msg);

  // checksum
  strTokIndex = strtok(NULL, "^");
  uint32_t checksum = atol(strTokIndex); // 2549230589
  serialPrintln(checksum);

  // verify checksum to ensure no packet corruption (todo : optimize)
  //...
}
```

I'm printing stuff to my serial monitor here and there with `serialPrintln()` in order to debug, and here is what it shows :

```
00:40:51.874 -> BAL^HUB^123^dark=456^2549230589
00:40:51.874 -> BAL
00:40:51.874 -> HUB
00:40:51.874 -> 123
00:40:51.874 -> dark=456
00:40:51.874 -> 2147483647
```

it prints the checksum as `2147483647` (2^31 - 1 ?) while it received `2549230589`

I must be wrong in the way I explode and parse my char array.

TL;DR : how do I explode a char array like `BAL^HUB^123^dark=456^2549230589` with the delimiter being `^`

Comment: Looks like integer overflow to me

Comment: print out the input to atol

Comment: to not use ^ simply replace the "^" strings by `"<whatever deilimiter you want>"` ie "+"

Comment: @pm100 Not sure what you meant but that is the case already, see ```uint32_t checksum = atol(strTokIndex);```

Comment: On the sender's side, atol reads 2549230589, which is what I expect. On the recipient's side, atol reads 2147483647, which is different and unexpected.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>    The  atoi() function converts the initial portion of the string pointed
>   to by nptr to int.  The behavior is the same as
>
>       strtol(nptr, NULL, 10);
>
>   except that atoi() does not detect errors.
>
>   The atol() and atoll() functions behave the same as atoi(), except that
>   they  convert the initial portion of the string to their return type of
>   long or long long.
> ```

> ```
>    The  strtol() function returns the result of the conversion, unless the
>   value would underflow or overflow.  If an  underflow  occurs,  strtol()
>   returns  LONG_MIN.   If  an overflow occurs, strtol() returns LONG_MAX.
>   In both cases, errno is set to ERANGE.  Precisely the  same  holds  for
>   strtoll()  (with  LLONG_MIN  and  LLONG_MAX  instead  of  LONG_MIN  and
>   LONG_MAX).
> ```

`2147483647` is larger than `LONG_MAX` so `LONG_MAX` is returned. There is no provision for reading an unsigned long. Using `atoll` will use at least 64bits and then you truncate the result to unsigned long (32bit). You can use that as workaround for parsing unsigned long. But that's even slower than `atol`. There is also `strtoul` which might be more appropriate.

Personally I would change the source to send the checksum as `uint32_t`, 4 raw bytes. Converting it to string and back is just waste of CPU power.

Comment: I am ```converting it to string and back``` because it is part of a single packet that flows through the air at 433 Mhz from machine1 <--> machine2 that are hundreds of meters separated from each other.  I have no other option.

Comment: @Musa Unless your packet is limited to ASCII you do have options.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: Yes, I am happy with the new formulation and have therefore deleted my comments.

Answer (score 0):

quickfixed it with `atoll()` instead of `atol()`

works with `strtoul(strTokIndex, NULL, 0)` as well.

Comment: You may want to explain in a few words why using `atoll` or `strtoul` instead of `atol` fixes the problem.